# Altering the listview of the django admin portal

Tags: django, django-admin, django-views

I've read, extensively, how to change the admin site of Django.  I have it mostly figured out -- I think.  However there are still a few things that elude me in my understanding.  I am using the default registered admin urls; so they are not customized, only what is exposed automatically.

The easiest way to explain this is through imagery...

Here's what I have:
[image: original admin layout]

Here's what I want:
[image]

I'm fairly certain the changes should be fairly simple.  But I don't know exactly which model to alter and template to adjust to get it to look how I want.  The [number] -- [name] are fields in my model.

I have extended other pieces of the admin interface to get customized forms for editing particular elements -- by registering my model and customizing the field for it.

```
@admin.register(Course)
class CourseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CourseAdminForm

    fieldsets = (
        ('Course Info:', {'fields': ('course_number', 'name', 'description', 'units')}),
        ('Load Info:', {'fields': ('lecture_hours', 'lab_hours', 'discussion_hours', 'work_hours')})
    )
```

in my `app/admin.py` file.

I'm a bit confused because there technically isn't a model to register here.  So I'm not 100% sure how to do this.  Do I wrap each one of my modifications inside the `CourseAdmin` class as different classes/methods with registered URLs or is there some other way I need to be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need edit your `Course` model class:

```
# models.py
class Course(models.Model):

    # fields here
    name = ...
    # ...

    # add a unicode method
    # __str__ method if you are using python 3.x
    def unicode(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.pk, self.name)
```

Comment: This worked.  Did I miss this in the documentation or something?

Comment: @lilott8 You can found documentation for this here -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#unicode

Comment: Thank you.  I would not have thought to look at the models documentation to affect change in the admin section.  I appreciate the answer and the documentation.